# How to monitor the health of a busy thread?

Tags: linux, multithreading, message-queue

I am working on an application that has numerous threads with each thread performing a task that is different from the other. There is also a healthMonitor thread that monitors health of individual threads by sending heartbeat messages at regular intervals. Among these threads there is one thread T1 that posts messages to another thread T2 in response to which T2 does some file write operation.

On rare occasions, T1 sends a surge of messages for a prolonged duration to T2, because of which T2 becomes busy with file write operations. Sometimes these file-write operations can be time consuming taking up to 2 seconds to complete. In this situation, T2 does not respond to the heartbeat messages posted by the healthMonitor thread, causing the healthMonitor thread to kill the application.

T2 reads all incoming messages including those posted by T1 and the hearbeat messages posted by the healthMonitor thread, from the same messageQueue.

This issue occurs very rarely and cannot be re-produced at will thus making it difficult to debug.

I have concluded that during such situations where there are huge number of messages pending to be processed and with the processing time taking too long, the heartbeat messages remain unprocessed for too long.  Because of this thread T2 does not respond to the healthMonitor thread on time.

My question is, what would be the proper way to handle this issue. I have few options in mind:

1. Limit the number of messages from thread T1. This approach would reduce the load from thread T2, but is this an elegant way to handle the situation?
2. Implement priority-based handling in the message queue: All heartbeat messages can be added to the head of the message queue instead of getting added to the tail so that it gets picked up first from the queue. Please note that we have our own implementation of message queue for inter-thread communication.
3. Or should I just focus on optimizing the file write operation in thread T2?

Comment: Have you considered not requesting heartbeats and have them automatically delivered by the task loop before looping back around to get the next message. Since the thread has to wake up periodically anyway to deal with the heartbeat requests, you don't lose anything by putting a time-out on the read from the message queue. Wake up, handle one message in the queue, if any, send heartbeat, loop back to reading from message queue. Downside is the monitor can get spammed if many short tasks are performed.

Comment: The above approach is good but the problem here is that the thread is fairly active, handling a message almost every second. Also, I am trying to understand, if I implement this mechanism for all threads wouldn't there be a flood of heartbeat messages every second during busy hours? The number of threads in the application is quite large.

Comment: It would get busy, but once a second is peanuts unless the message-passing interface is an expensive one. The message could be a simple as the monitored thread setting an atomic flag and the monitor scanning a list of flags, checking and clearing them. If the flag goes too long without being set, Uh-oh.